# How to change the URL of the edit post link?

Tags: wordpress

I want to change the URL of the edit post link so that it directs you to my own custom edit page. I've been looking for a filter or function but all I can find is the `edit_post_link()` function and the `get_edit_post_link()` function. From what I can see from [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/edit_post_link), `edit_post_link` only changes the links text, not the URL. And `get_edit_post_link` I believe gets the URL for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to add a filter to `get_edit_post_link`. This is untested, but something like:

```
add_filter( 'get_edit_post_link', 'my_edit_post_link' );
function my_edit_post_link( $url, $post->ID, $context) {
    $url = //However you want to generate your link

    return $url;
}
```

Comment: I wish I'd just waited for replies lol. I kept trying to figure it out and eventually figured out that wordpress prints the links in link-template.php so I just modified that. However, that won't work for writing plugins so I'll use get_edit_post_link instead, thanks.

Comment: If that is the "correct" answer for your situation, please remember to upvote and more importantly, mark an answer as accepted so that others will know what the solution is.

Comment: @JenniferO'Brien click the check button underneath the up/down voting arrows beside the answer.

Screenshot: http://d.pr/i/LSmF

Comment: The $post->ID is throwing an error as an argument for the function.  I know this is untested but was there ever a working solution?

Comment: @Derek Yes, it should be `$post_id`, not `$post->ID`. Also, the call to add_filter needs to specify that it should accept three parameters, otherwise it defaults to 1 and doesn't work. i.e. `add_filter( 'get_edit_post_link', 'my_edit_post_link', 10, 3 );` See [working example, below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63288659/264547), if you happen to still care about this, five years on..

Answer (score 1):

Working version:

```
add_filter( 'get_edit_post_link', 'my_edit_post_link', 10, 3 );
function my_edit_post_link( $url, $post_id, $context) {
    $url = "http://somethingerother.com/custom_post_editor.php?post=".$post_id; // Modify the URL as desired

    return $url;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

my wordpress dev skills are a little rusted but you should probably use wordpress [hooks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API) to hook [`edit_post`](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/edit_post)  , and write your plugin to rewrite the return value or `do_action` to just go yo your own custion edit page

Comment: I know about hooks, the edit_post hook just modifies what happens when you submit the text editor, its got nothing to do with the edit post link.